# Toggle a specific Text with JavaScript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor, toggle

I have a toggle button that changes a bit of text. The problem I run into is if I have 2 words and I want to change the text of one it changes one but when I toggle it off style is removed from both spans instead of the span of the selected text.

How can I remove the span from the specific text selected and leave the span on the other text?

```js
function headuppercase(e) {
  tags('span', 'sC');
}

function tags(tag, clas) {
  var ele = document.createElement(tag);
  ele.classList.add(clas);
  wrap(ele);
}

function wrap(tags) {
  var el = document.querySelector('span.sC');
  sel = window.getSelection();
  if (!el) {
    if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
    document.designMode = "on";
    if (range) {
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
    range.surroundContents(tags);
  } else {
    var parent = el.parentNode;
    while (el.firstChild) parent.insertBefore(el.firstChild, el);
    parent.removeChild(el);
  }
  document.designMode = "off";
}
```

```css
.ourbutton {
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

.spanA {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
  float: left;
  border: thin blue solid;
}

.sC {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<button class="ourbutton" type="button" onclick="headuppercase();">Tt</button>
<div class="container">
  <span class="spanA" contenteditable="true"></span>
</div>
```

No jQuery please. Thanks You!

Comment: How did you plan to solve if someone selects character within Sc-span along with characters without ? Is it gonna look like this: **bb**rr**b** (** bb ** rr ** b **)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so easily achievable without a library because of all the edge cases you need to handle. I will first touch on some edge cases and then give you an example on how to implement them.

### Simple case

Say we have the following string inside a text Node

> "Nobody wants too complex code because it becomes unmanageable."

Consider a user who selected the words *"Nobody wants"* and pressed the toggle small caps button. You should end up with something looking like this (where the bold segments represent text in small-caps):

> "**Nobody wants** too complex code because it becomes unmanageable."

This is an easy case. Just wrap the segment "**Nobody wants**" inside a `<span>` and give it the `sC` class. The same goes for all other segments that are not yet in small caps. Nothing too hard here.

### Edge case 1

But say you are in the following state (again, bold segments represent text in small-caps) :

> "Nobody wants too complex code **because it becomes unmanageable.**"

When the user selects and toggles the word *"becomes"* things become complicated. You have to:

1. Remove the last two words from their containing `<span class="sC">` element
2. Add the word *"becomes"* after the span (from step 1.) and make sure it is not contained in a `<span>` that has the className `sC`.
3. Add the word *"unmanageable"* inside a new `<span class="sC">` element after the text Node *"becomes"* (that was inserted in step 2.)

### Edge case 2

Or say you are in the following state (again, bold segments represent text in small-caps) :

> "**Nobody wants** too **complex** code **because it becomes unmanageable.**"

What should happen when somebody selects and toggles the segment *"wants too complex code because"* ? One could say: make every character in this segment

- *small-caps* : when it is not
- *back to normal* : when it is currently small-caps

It's easy to see that you will again need a lot of *splitting existing span elements*, *creating new text nodes*, and so forth

### Edge case N

Say you start with a nested list

> - A
>
>   - B
>   - C
> - D

and a user selects the two last items at once. Then you need to wrap each item separately into a span.

## First step towards a solution

While it is not clear in your question how all the edge cases should be handled, here is a first step towards a solution.

```js
const allCapsClass = 'sC'
function toggleCase() {
 const selection = window.getSelection()
  if (selection && selection.rangeCount>0) {
   const spans = wrapInNonNestedSpanners(selection.getRangeAt(0))
    for (const span of spans) {
     const classes = span.classList
     const action = classes.contains(allCapsClass) ? 'remove' : 'add'
      classes[action](allCapsClass)
    }
  }
}


const spannerClassName = "non-nested-spanner"
const spannerQuerySelector = `.${spannerClassName}`

function wrapInNonNestedSpanners(range) {
 const containingSpanner = getContainingSpanner(range)
 const result = []
 if (containingSpanner != null) { // Edge case 1
   const endRange = document.createRange() // contents of the span after range
   endRange.selectNode(containingSpanner)
   endRange.setStart(range.endContainer, range.endOffset)
   const endContents = endRange.cloneContents()
   const wrappedSelectionContents = containingSpanner.cloneNode(false)
   wrappedSelectionContents.appendChild(range.cloneContents())
   endRange.deleteContents()
   range.deleteContents()
   const parent = containingSpanner.parentNode
   const next = containingSpanner.nextSibling
   parent.insertBefore(wrappedSelectionContents, next)
   result.push(wrappedSelectionContents)
   if (!isEmptySpanner(endContents.childNodes[0])) parent.insertBefore(endContents, next)
   if (isEmptySpanner(containingSpanner)) parent.removeChild(containingSpanner)
   const newSelection = document.createRange()
   newSelection.selectNode(wrappedSelectionContents)
   window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
   window.getSelection().addRange(newSelection)
 } else { // Edge case 2
  const contents = range.extractContents()
  const spanners = contents.querySelectorAll(spannerQuerySelector)
  let endRange = document.createRange() // range before the span
  for (let index = spanners.length-1; index>=0; index--) {
   const spanner = spanners[index]
   endRange.selectNodeContents(contents)
   endRange.setStartAfter(spanner)
   if (!endRange.collapsed) {
    const wrappedEndContents = createSpannerWrapping(endRange.extractContents())
    range.insertNode(wrappedEndContents)
    result.unshift(wrappedEndContents)
   }
   range.insertNode(spanner)
   result.unshift(spanner)
  }
  const rest = createSpannerWrapping(contents)
  if (!isEmptySpanner(rest)) {
   range.insertNode(rest)
   result.unshift(rest)
  }
 }
 return result
}

function getContainingSpanner(range) {
 let cursor = range.commonAncestorContainer
 if (cursor.classList == undefined) cursor = cursor.parentElement
 while (cursor.parentElement != null) {
  if (cursor.classList.contains(spannerClassName)) return cursor
  cursor = cursor.parentElement
 }
 return null
}

function createSpannerWrapping(childNode) {
 const spanner = document.createElement('span')
 spanner.classList.add(spannerClassName)
 spanner.appendChild(childNode)
 return spanner
}

function isEmptySpanner(spanner) {
 if (spanner.childNodes.length == 0) return true
 else if (spanner.childNodes.length == 1) {
  const node = spanner.childNodes[0]
  return node instanceof Text && node.length == 0
 }
 return false
}
```

```css
.sC {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<section contenteditable>
  Hello world this is some text
</section>
<button onclick="toggleCase()">Toggle case</button>
```

Comment: This is a very good example.   I will play with it a bit.  Thank you much

Comment: This has a very good explanation, and works Beautifully Thank you for your time on this example.  Well Done.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with this `document.querySelector('span.sC')`. In all the case it will select the first span with sC which is not good as you have to deal with the current one.

Here is an idea of fix:

```js
function headuppercase(e) {
  tags('span', 'sC');
}

function tags(tag, clas) {
  var ele = document.createElement(tag);
  ele.classList.add(clas);
  wrap(ele);
}

function wrap(tags) {
  sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
    document.designMode = "on";
    if (range) {
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
    range.surroundContents(tags);
    if(tags.querySelector('.sC')) {
      tags.classList.remove('sC');
      tags.innerHTML=tags.querySelector('.sC').innerHTML;
    }
  document.designMode = "off";
}
```

```css
.ourbutton {
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

.spanA {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 300px;
  float: left;
  border: thin blue solid;
}

.sC {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<button class="ourbutton" type="button" onclick="headuppercase();">Tt</button>
<div class="container">
  <span class="spanA" contenteditable="true"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is close, but still a bit buggy.  If you select 2 it will error out if you try to toggle the style off.  I will play and see what i can do with it thank you.  Im thinking i need to get all spans in an array and and effect just the selected span.  Just not really sure how to go about it..